# How to validate dependencies' java version when compiling using higher version JDK?

Tags: java, java-8, javac, java-6

We're using java 8 for most modules/projects, but for some of the modules, we use java 6 (customer requirements).

The developers have java 8 installed and we compile the java 6 projects using these flags:

```
compileJava {
    sourceCompatibility = 1.6
    targetCompatibility = 1.6
}
```

We thought we're all good until we upgraded guava from `v20` to latest - `28.1-jre`.

To our surprise, the build was successful but failed at runtime.

We have a workaround for building for java 6 using a specific `javac` found in JDK 6. See more info [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/building_java_projects.html). This workaround wields the error `class file has wrong version 52.0, should be 50.0` in compile time. The downside is that it requires a download+config+usage of JDK 6 for developers.

**Is there a way to validate the dependencies' java version at compile time when using a higher java version?** (without installing lower version java) Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Setting `-source` and `-target` values to 1.6 is *insufficient* to ensure that the resulting output is compatible with 1.6. The program itself must not have any library API dependencies on later versions, and the `-source` and `-target` options don't do that. (GhostCat said pretty much the same thing.)

For example, in Java 8, `ConcurrentHashMap` added a covariant override for the [`keySet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#keySet--) method that returns a new type `ConcurrentHashMap.KeySetView`. This type didn't exist in earlier versions of Java. However, in the class binary, the return type is encoded at the call site. Thus, even if the source code is compiled with `-source 1.6 -target 1.6`, the resulting class file contains a dependency on the Java 8 class library API.

The only solution to this is to ensure that only Java 1.6 compatible libraries are in the classpath at compile time. This can be done using the `-Xbootclasspath` option to point to a JDK 1.6 class library, or it might be simpler just to use a JDK 1.6 installation in the first place.

This applies to external libraries in addition to the JDK, as you've discovered with Guava. The [Animal Sniffer](https://www.mojohaus.org/animal-sniffer/animal-sniffer/index.html) project provides plugins for Ant and Maven that checks library dependencies for version problems. Offhand I don't know if there is something similar for Gradle. There might be a way to get Animal Sniffer to work with Gradle, but I have no experience with doing that.

Comment: Nice link though. I wonder how they do that ... scanning libraries automatically  ... or someone keeping track of compatibility levels by manually reading and updating some really huge database ;-)

Comment: Or use `javac` of an even newer JDK, say JDK 11, together with the `--release 6` option.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a way to validate the dependencies' java version at compile time when using a higher java version? (without installing lower version java).

You specify your dependencies. When you tell your built system to explicitly use some library X in version Y, then you made a very clear statement.

And you see, it is not only about the *class file version* number. What if some person doesn't pay attention, and compiles something with Java8 ... with Java6 target, but forgets that the code bases uses Java8-only API calls?!

In other words: you are looking in the wrong place.

The person who makes updates to the build description, and changes a library version from Y to Y+8, *that* person needs to carefully assess that change. For example by reading release letters.

I agree that a really clever build system could check if libraries you are using come in with a matching class file version. But as said, that is only *one* aspect of the problem. So instead of looking into a technical solution, I think the real answer is: don't step version numbers because you **can**, but because you have to. And that manual step of changing that version number, that is something that requires due diligence (on the side of the human doing it).

Thus: I think the *most sane* approach here is to compile the Java6 deliverables within their own specific build setup. Which you only touch after careful inspection of such details. And sure: convince your customer to move on, and give up a long dead version of Java.

Comment: I see the java SDK as a dependency like any other. Bummer it doesn't work this way.

Comment: @AlikElzin-kilaka No, unfortunately it is not. Rather look at it as the essential foundation of your build setup. It is the one dependancy that constrains **any** other dependancy in your setup.